# Code to be executed before every page on server

Tags: apache2, system-administration

I have an apache2 server, it has a vast and growing folder structure.

There is a set of instructions I would like to be executed at the beginning of every page in that website.

How do I implement that without pasting those very lines at the beginning of every file in the website?

- I don't want to have the code at the beginning of every file.
- I have tried changing the `auto_prepend_file` in php.ini to:
  `auto_prepend_file = ~/website_preview/say_hello.php`

'say_hello' is a hello-world php script, but the script does still not get executed at all.

Comment: Probably it won't be possible to happen the way you envision it. If you provide more details about what exactly you want to do at the beginning of every page, there might be some other way to achieve it.

Comment: It's just loading modules i want to load on every page of the site automatically. And I have the entire website available locally and it must also work there, without changing it.

Comment: You've stated that most of your pages are html, what kind of modules do you want to load there?

Comment: It's html,php and js. Sometimes theres pure js, sometimes theres pure php and sometimes they're mixed within.

Comment: So, your pages are actually PHP, and you want to execute the same PHP code at the start of every request? In this case `auto_prepend_file` is really the right way. I would suggest you put the absolute path to your `say_hello.php` file there, since I don't think PHP would parse correctly the tilde in your path.

Comment: ive changed it to: auto_prepend_file = ":/home/hermann/website_preview/say_hello.php"   and restarted the server, but the script doesnt seem to execute.

Comment: It should not start with a colon

Comment: Can you run it on the command line? `php /home/hermann/website_preview/say_hello.php`?

Comment: good point, i was not able to since it was labeled .php but had <?php ?> within it. I fixed that, now i can run it with php and have changed in php.ini accordingly and restarted the server. But auto_prepend is still not working.

Comment: .php files **are** supposed to have `<?php ?>` in them, but you should be able to run it with the `<?php ?>` in place. Can you provide the content of that script?

Comment: hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
<?php
echo "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii";
?>

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your apache error log when you try to access a page on your site? Can you check the output of `phpinfo()` and see what it shows for `auto_prepend_file` in the "Core" section?

Comment: in the core section of phpinfo() it says: auto_prepend_file no value no value
browscap no value no value"

Comment: Where is my apache error log? The error log in the website home directory has no errors more recent than march.

Comment: Are you adding `auto_prepend_file` to your `php.ini`, or to a `.htaccess` file? Apparently PHP is not seeing your `auto_prepend_file` setting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11871/discussion-between-lanzz-and-hermann-ingjaldsson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong `php.ini` file, correct location is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: in php, phpinfo() displays information about the given server. There "Loaded configuration file" indicates which php.ini file is being used.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your pages are in PHP, then I think you were on the right path with setting up `auto_prepend_file` in php.ini.

Try this:

1. Check your `include_path` in php.ini and if needed append a new path to it for your instructions file.
2. Copy your instructions.php file to the location from the include path.
3. Edit your `auto_prepend_file` in php.ini to be just the filename from step 2.

I tested this out and was able to get it working that way but had trouble specifying the path directly in the `auto_prepend_file` setting.

Also, when I had the `auto_prepend_file` setting configured improperly I received the following php error:
*PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required ...*

Hope that helps.

Comment: Most of my pages are html, and some are js.

Comment: I tried this but the script simply doesn't get executed before the pages do.

Comment: The auto_prepend_file setting will only work on php files, not html or javascript. If it isn't working you can try using phpinfo() to verify your configuration. Perhaps someone else can chime in with a solution for your non-php pages.